# Browser Suddenly gets kicked out of client certificate authenticated site on Apache Windows Environment

Tags: certificates, windows, openssl, apache

I have a website in our development environment "Windows / Apache 2.4 server" that has client certificate authentication.

When you initially visit the site, it works ok. Since I have multiple client certificate installed, the Client Certificate prompt will appear. I select the correct client cert and it will work as expected.

But for some random time. It will just suddenly not work. All server request would fail. When you change the address bar to go to the site directly it shows the SSL fail error. The display is similar to what is displayed when you do not select a Client Certificate during the initial prompt.

I have to restart the browser / open a new tab and it works again. The client certificate selection dialog is shown again.

This only happens in our development environment. On the production hosted in CentOS, it is OK. Also, this happens in all browser.

Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

**SSL Error Displayed:**

For IE the message show is:

> This page can't be displayed. Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1...

My browser is in another language so I just tried to find the translation from Internet.

[image]

**My Browser Settings:**

- SSL 2.0 Enabled - Unchecked
- SSL 3.0 Enabled - Unchecked
- TSL 1.0 Enabled - Checked
- TSL 1.1 Enabled - Checked
- TSL 1.2 Enabled - Checked

Comment: What exactly is the SSL failure error?

Comment: As forest mentioned, what exactly is the SSL error? Also, what do you have setup differently in regards to the SSL cert in your dev environment vs your prod environment?